# How to enable profiling tools in IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2

Tags: java, intellij-idea, profiling

IntelliJ IDEA 2019.2 [has been released](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2019-2) with a new feature "[Profiling Tools](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/whatsnew/#v2019-2-profiling-tools)".

I updated my version to 2019.2 (Ultimate), yet I don't see any of the options shown on the change log page. Moreover I can't find any official documentation regarding how to turn on the feature. I searched briefly and all I could find is some screenshots of clicking on a menu item that doesn't exist in my freshly updated version.

How can I use new integrated profiling tools? Do I need to change some settings?

Answer (score 4):

Profiler has to be configured in `Settings -> Build, Execution, Deployment -> Java Profiler`.

Comment: You also need `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` in the VM Options of the Run/Debug configuration to use the Java Flight Recorder profiler.

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks. Is it required for some specific JDKs/JREs?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/java.html: -XX:+|-FlightRecorder
Toggles the use of the Java Flight Recorder (JFR) during the runtime of the application. This is a commercial feature that requires you to also specify the `-XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures` option as follows: `java -XX:UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder`